# Intent.getStringExtra() returns null in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I don't know what mistake I am doing why it is returning null, I have seen other people problems I am not getting what I need exactly. **I am sending the string data in this activity**

```
            val inspenctionIntent = Intent(this, InspectActivity::class.java)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Particulars", estimateItem.Particulars)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("SSRItemNO", estimateItem.SSRItemNO)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Quantity", estimateItem.Quantity)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("QuantityUnit", estimateItem.QuantityUnit)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Times", estimateItem.Times)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Rates", estimateItem.Rates)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("RatesPer", estimateItem.RatesPer)
            inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Total", estimateItem.Total)
            startActivity(Intent(this@CheckMeasurementActivity, InspectActivity::class.java))
```

and trying to get that string extra in another activity but is returning null?

```
    val Particulars = intent.getStringExtra("Particulars")
    val SSRItemNO = intent.getStringExtra("SSRItemNO")
    val Quantity = intent.getStringExtra("Quantity")
    val QuantityUnit = intent.getStringExtra("QuantityUnit")
    val Times = intent.getStringExtra("Times")
    val Rates = intent.getStringExtra("Rates")
    val RatesPer = intent.getStringExtra("RatesPer")
    val Total = intent.getStringExtra("Total")
```

I tried by replacing var also still it is returning null?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is this line.

```
startActivity(Intent(this@CheckMeasurementActivity, InspectActivity::class.java))
```

You declare `inspenctionIntent` but never use it, so others activity will get nothing since your intent send nothing to it.

So you need to change

```
startActivity(Intent(this@CheckMeasurementActivity, InspectActivity::class.java))
```

to

```
startActivity(inspenctionIntent)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are started wrong intent so should use `inspenctionIntent` inside `startActivity()`

```
       val inspenctionIntent = Intent(this, InspectActivity::class.java)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Particulars", estimateItem.Particulars)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("SSRItemNO", estimateItem.SSRItemNO)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Quantity", estimateItem.Quantity)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("QuantityUnit", estimateItem.QuantityUnit)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Times", estimateItem.Times)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Rates", estimateItem.Rates)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("RatesPer", estimateItem.RatesPer)
        inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Total", estimateItem.Total)
        startActivity(inspenctionIntent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
Intent.putExtra("Particulars", estimateItem.Particulars)
```

Instead of

```
 inspenctionIntent.putExtra("Particulars", estimateItem.Particulars)
```

and for others is the same.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: I use this method for sending data from one activity to another one and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this-:

```
startActivity(Intent(this@CheckMeasurementActivity, InspectActivity::class.java))
```

to-:

```
startActivity(inspenctionIntent)
```

in last line of your code...